# Keep requested host to endpoint with Apache Camel

Tags: rest, proxy, apache-camel

I use Apache Camel like a smart HTTP proxy, in front of REST APIs. I have a configuration file with routes to configure and it works great.

To avoid complexity, I will summerize the code by :

```
camelContext.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder(){
            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
                from("servlet:///v1.3?matchOnUriPrefix=true")
                    .to("http4://localhost:8080/my-rest-api-v1.3.0?bridgeEndpoint=true&throwExceptionOnFailure=false");
                from("servlet:///v1.2?matchOnUriPrefix=true")
                    .to("http4://localhost:8080/my-rest-api-v1.2.1?bridgeEndpoint=true&throwExceptionOnFailure=false");
            }
        });
```

My problem is on the endpoint server. When I retrieve the Request URL from my HttpServletRequest, it gives me a "http://localhost:8080/my-rest-api-v1.3.0/resources/companies/" instead of "http://my.site.com/my-rest-api" (which is the URL of my proxy).

How can I transfer requested host name to my endpoint?

I don't find how to do it with Apache Camel.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP request has properies (like 'host') in its Header and to use this property in camel you need just replace `localhost:8080` with `${header.host}` and use recipientList EIP (so you can use Simple language to create an URI):

```
    camelContext.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder(){
        @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {
            from("servlet:///v1.3?matchOnUriPrefix=true")
                .recipientList(simple("http4://${header.host}/my-rest-api-v1.3.0?bridgeEndpoint=true&throwExceptionOnFailure=false"));
            from("servlet:///v1.2?matchOnUriPrefix=true")
                .recipientList(simple("http4://${header.host}/my-rest-api-v1.2.1?bridgeEndpoint=true&throwExceptionOnFailure=false"));
        }
    });
```

UPDATED: I updated the code above according to the next link: http://camel.apache.org/how-do-i-use-dynamic-uri-in-to.html (to use dynamic uri you have to use recipient List EIP).

Comment: Ok. It does'nt seem to work here. I'm working in Java. Do you work in Groovy, or is it specified by Camel ?

Comment: Nicolas, you are right. Simple language is not working in to(..). To construct an URI you have to use recipientList pattern: http://camel.apache.org/how-do-i-use-dynamic-uri-in-to.html . I've updated my answer.